# Can one know the rank of a matrix product given the rank of one of them?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose we have some matrix $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. We have another matrix $T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, which happens to be full-rank.

I'm wondering if it is possible to know the rank of the matrix built as $$\hat{Q}=QT$$

My intuition says that, due to $T$ being an injection, $\mathrm{rank}(\hat{Q})=\mathrm{rank}(Q)$, but I'm not sure about this. I find it easy to arrive to this conclusion if the matrix was $\hat{Q}=TQ$, with $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ but not with the $T$ at the right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea: combine
$$
\text{rank}\,\hat Q=\text{rank}\,QT\le\text{rank}\,Q
$$
and
$$
\text{rank}\,Q=\text{rank}\,\hat QT^{-1}\le\text{rank}\,\hat Q.
$$

Answer (score 3):

The rank is the dimension of the image. Since $T$ is injective and injective maps preserve dimension (as they map linearly independent sets to linearly independent sets), it follows that $T$ is also surjective. So the image of $T$ is $\mathbb R^n$. It follows that the image of $QT$ is equal to the image of $Q$, so in particular
$$
\text{rank}\, Q=\text{rank}\,QT.
$$

Comment: No quite.  If T maps all vectors to the null space of Q, then the rank of (QT) would be 0.  So, it is more complicated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. $T$ is a bijective map $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$; it has no "room" to map all vectors to the kernel of $Q$, as $Q$ maps $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$. With $T$ bijective, every possible vector in the domain of $Q$ is offered to $Q$.

Comment: @ulaff.net If $T$ maps all vectors to the null space of $Q$, then the null space of $Q$ would have to be $\mathbb{R}^n$. If this is true, then $Q$ should have rank $0$, thus $Q = \mathbf{0}$, and this is not a pretty interesting case.

Comment: You are right.  I did not read the question carefully!

Comment: No worries. Happened twice to me today.